# Необходимость запятой в тексте "на вас, по договору №123 от 01.01.2020, назначена задача LO-123"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я предполагаю, что в предложении "на вас, по договору №123 от 01.01.2020, назначена задача LO-123" не нужны запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Запятые факультативны, их постановка зависит от автора: считает ли он ***по договору №123 от 01.01.2020*** пояснением и произносит ли предложение с паузами на месте запятых. Оба варианта - с обособлением и без него - являются корректными.

Я бы обособила пояснение.